# RewriteRule in my .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a problem with query strings. I want to change this...

http://www.audiomasterclass.com/arc.cfm?a=giant-killing-%245-mic-preamp-its-secrets-reveale

To this...

www.audiomasterclass.com/?a=588

Comment: You'll have to pull the id from the your database based on the slug.  mod_rewrite can do a lot of magic, but it can't do that.  As for the actual rewriting, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this url it can't be done. You need logic to reverse the name to a ID.

What you can do is make sure that in the original url the ID is included. For instance:

http://www.audiomasterclass.com/arc.cfm?a=giant-killing-%245-mic-preamp-its-secrets-reveale
can be changed to: http://www.audiomasterclass.com/588/giant-killing-%245-mic-preamp-its-secrets-reveale

And then use a rewrite rule:
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+) /arc.cfm?a=$1 [L]

What you do is add the id to every link so you system will on basis of ID but google/users see the nice URL.

You need to change the rewrite rule a bit (for your needs and server config) but it will explain the basics.

Comment: # RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} example=  
# RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1? [R=301]